# When does iisnode create stdout log files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stdout, iisnode

I'm deploying my first node app and running into some issues. I am using iisnode and can see that it writes stdout log files which contain useful console logs from my app. What triggers these log files to be written?

Comment: Those files are written as error, when the app crash... or won't run.. and as output for your console.log calls for instance.